# printing multiplication table in python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to print the multiplication table using dictionary.Suppose,if a user enters a number then i want the multiplication of next 10numbers to be print in dictionary format as:

```
multiplication_table = {
  "2" : { 
    "2 X 1" : 2, 
    "2 X 2" : 4,
    "2 X 3" : 6,
    "2 X 4" : 8,
    "2 X 5" : 10,
    "2 X 6" : 12,
    "2 X 7" : 14,
    "2 X 8" : 16,
    "2 X 9" : 18,
    "2 X 10" : 20,
  },
  "3" :{
    .
    .
    .
  }
}
```

So,I tried:

```
g = input("Enter the number of multiplication to be print") 
for x in range(1,10):
  a=x
  b=g*x
  multiplication_table = {
    a:b
  };
print(multiplication_table);
```

I am not getting the expected output.How can I get the expected output?

Comment: "I am not getting the expected output" What happens instead?

Comment: It looks like you have at least four problems here: the dict is too short, the dict is flat, you're multiplying a string, and your dict keys aren't correct. Which one are you asking about? Note that SO is Q&A site, not a code-writing service. See [ask] for guidelines.

Comment: BTW get rid of the semicolons. They do nothing.

Comment: ok thank you i am beginner of python .learning it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
g = int(input("Enter number: ")) # g is the input number

multiplication_table = {} # defines the dictionary
for i in range(1, 11): # iterates from i = 1, 2, ..., 10
    multiplication_table[str(g) + " x " + str(i)] = g*i

print(multiplication_table)
```

In this code, str(g) + " x " + str(i) basically appends the numbers g and i to a string, i.e. the string "5 x 4". Then, the value is set to g*i (20 in this example).

**Edit**

To answer Random Guy's comment:

```
g = int(input("Enter number: ")) # g is the input number

multiplication_table = {} # defines the dictionary
for i in range(1, 10*int(g/10) + 11): 
    multiplication_table[str(g) + " x " + str(i)] = g*i

print(multiplication_table)
```

Comment: Slightly simpler to make the key: `f'{g} x {i}'`

Comment: but suppose if i enter 10 then, i need to show multiplication upto 20 in dictionary

Comment: @Randomguy i've edited my answer to address your comment.

Answer (score 0):

You are not updating the dictionary in right way.

```
g = int(input("Enter the number of multiplication to be print: "))
multiplication_table = {}

for x in range(1, 11):
    multiplication_table.update(
        {x: g * x}
    )

for key in multiplication_table:
    print(str(g) + " X " + str(key) + " = " + str(multiplication_table[key]))
```

Comment: Yes, Edited it.Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
g = input("Enter the number of multiplication to be print") 

for x in range(1,10):
  print("%s × %s = %s" % (g,x,int(g)*x))
```

```
4 × 1 = 4
4 × 2 = 8
4 × 3 = 12
4 × 4 = 16
4 × 5 = 20
4 × 6 = 24
4 × 7 = 28
4 × 8 = 32
4 × 9 = 36
```

Comment: While this code may resolve the OP's issue, it is best to include an explanation as to how your code addresses the OP's issue. In this way, future visitors can learn from your post, and apply it to their own code. SO is not a coding service, but a resource for knowledge. Also, high quality, complete answers are more likely to be upvoted. These features, along with the requirement that all posts are self-contained, are some of the strengths of SO as a platform, that differentiates it from forums. You can edit to add additional info &/or to supplement your explanations with source documentation.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```py
def multiplication_table(base=2):
    return {str(i):f'{base} X {i}' for i in range(1, 10)}

dictionary = multiplication_table(2)
print(dictionary)
```